# PHP/Laravel get last word in a a class name: App\Models\Example\Class; and lowercase it: class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, laravel-5.7

Anyone see a simpler/cleaner way of going about this? I have polymorphic types that are stored as a full class name and I need to access the last word in the class and lowercase it to locate a config file:

Examle: `$this->ant_type = App\Models\AntTypes\Request`

```
$antTypeArray = explode('\\', $this->ant_type);
$workflow = strtolower(array_values(array_slice($antTypeArray, -1))[0]);
```

It certainly works fine, just curious if there's an even simpler way to go about it. I'm using Laravel 5.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this with PHPs `ReflectionClass`.

```php
$workflow = strtolower((new \ReflectionClass($this->ant_type))->getShortName());
```

Comment: Beat me to it by couple of seconds :P I like this a bit better. If that class doesn't exist, it will also thrown an exception.

Comment: I like this! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Just be aware that reflection is [*slightly*](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20850f8c79d48b2f095cc1ff1d97bff939fae30a) slower than string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Find the last `\` and take the substring from that point + 1 to the end of the string:

```
strtolower(substr($str, strrpos($str, '\\') + 1))
```

Code golfed for shortness, but produces E_NOTICE

```
strtolower(end(explode('\\',$str)))
```